# How to use session in php backend

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I'm developing an AngularJs application with PHP backend, I implemented the authentication step, and now I'm trying to display data of authenticated user in another view after authentication. Here are the two files.php in which I implement the sessions: the first one (login.php) is called by login function, and the second (info.php) is called by other function to display user data.

Even if I did what I read in some tutorials about sessions and tokens more than two weeks, I still can't display user data.
Can you help me, please?

**login.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
       $_SESSION["naam"] = $Email; 
       $result['code'] = 200;
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['role'] = 'client';
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;
  }


       $result['code'] = 603;
       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';



$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

**info.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT NomClient,PrenomClient,EmailClient FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check if logged in function in the info.php, example:

```
<?php 
      session_start();
      if ($_SESSION["logged_in"] == false) 
      {
          echo "you need to be logged in to view this page!"; 
          die();
      }
```